# Sending the XML from JAXB by Smack xmpp api

Tags: xml, jaxb, smack

I would like to know what is the best way to send raw XML by smack api. I mean, I can send strings as messages to some people in my contact list (aka friends). But I would like to send them just some XML. Should I build XML, convert it to string, send it and then parse the string back to an xml at the receiver side? Is this recommended?

I was thinking about converting some class by JAXB to an XML, send it as a string and unmarshall it on the receiver side back to the class. Is it valid way of doing things? Is there some best practice how to do it?

Thank you a lot

Answer (score 0):

Check out [PacketExtension](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/packet/PacketExtension.html) and [PacketExtensionProvider](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/providers.html).  Extensions provide a custom means of adding XML extensions to different packet types and the provider is the matching unmarshalling mechanism.

If you check the source code you will see many examples of it's usage.  There is no direct support for jaxb, but I would think you should be able to write an extension and provider that use JAXB.

Comment: Hmmm, but, aren't these packet extensions somehow parts of the XMPP protocol, which I "extended" by them? I do not want to extend the XMPP protocol, I just need to send XML as a message. I know what you mean but I do not want to modify XMPP by adding my own stuff. XMPP is good for me as it is right now. I am just struggling with sending XML as a message.

Comment: And this is not only XML. Take HTML. It seems to me that XMPP as such is appropriate to use with simple strings. If I need to send some other message, somehow formatted, the only possibility to do so is just convert it to string and send it and parse it back on arriving ... and maybe I am wrong.